# C++ Builder XE5 linker error LME1641

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I'm having trouble building a project in XE5. I made some basic changes that would in no way cause an issue, but the project fails to build. I have verified that these changes build fine on another machine, and that the projects continues to build on my machine if I undo these changes.

I have managed to narrow the cause down to the code trying to use a member variable, but it's clear this is not the actual reason for the link failure.

I have tried clearing temp files as this seems to have worked for a similar issue:
[C++ Builder XE7 LME288 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929516/c-builder-xe7-lme288-error)

but this does not fix the problem. For reference, i am receiving the following:

```
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: unknown heap name   : 0x08000000 / 0x08000000
[ilink32 Warning] Warning: Error detected (LME1641)
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

I'm being driven crazy by this, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out eventually, the .cbproj file had been tainted from a recent merge.

The issue was extremely sporadic, as some branches with the same project file were building, and some were not. If you're having this issue check that your project file contains the appropriate information!